# Cut first line in text file and paste into another file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I need a batch file to cut the first line of a `file1.txt`, save this file, paste the line to `file2.txt` and save this second file; in particular I want it to overwrite the second file, here's an example

`File1.txt`:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

`File2.txt` is empty. I want to transfer the first line to the second file so that

`File1.txt`

```
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

And `File2.txt` will be:

```
line 1
```

Save both files. When I run the batch file again, I want it to overwrite the second file so that:

`File1.txt`

```
line 3
line 4
```

And `File2.txt` will be:

```
line 2
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible...

Comment: Search this site and you'll find numerous examples...

Comment: @aschipfl i already searched, didn't find what i was looking for

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a free code/script writing service, neither is it a tutorial site. You need to provide a [mcve] of your coding attempts and ask a specific question (see [ask]); otherwise this post is off-topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the following way:

```bat
@echo off

set "file1=file1.txt"
set "file2=file2.txt"

goto :first_loop

:first_loop
for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('type "%file1%"') do (
    (echo %%A)>"%file2%"
    goto :second_loop
)

:second_loop
for /F "skip=1 delims= eol=" %%A IN ('type "%file1%" ^& del "%file1%"') do (echo %%A)>>"%file1%"
if not exist "%file1%" (type nul >%file1%)
goto :completion

:completion
echo Completed!
pause>nul
exit /b
```

where actually in the first loop you `echo` the first line to the second file and in the second one, you actually remove the first line of your first file.

See:

- `for /?`
- `type /?`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`

for more information.

Comment: This actually work for me, thanks! But when there is only 1 line in file1.txt, it transfer this line to file2.txt and it deletes my file1.txt, how can i make it to leave it blank instead of deleting it?